How to use custom controller to delete indexed dynamically created container widgets
I am new to creating custom controllers, but I'm trying to dynamically create/remove container widgets while being able to add data to each one independently of each other. When I remove the widgets, I am trying to specifically select which one to remove and research suggested creating indexed controllers is what I am after, but I'm having issues implementing this.
The custom controller is this:
class WidgetController extends ChangeNotifier {

  void removeWidget(controller, index) {
    controller[index].dispose();
    controller.removeAt(index);
  }

  void addWidget(controller) {
    controller.add(WidgetController());
  }
}

The dynamic container widget that is to be created/removed is this:
class DynamicWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicWidget({
    required this.controller,
    required this.index,
    super.key,
  });

  final List<WidgetController> controller;
  final int index;

  @override
  State<DynamicWidget> createState() => _DynamicWidget();
}

class _DynamicWidget extends State<DynamicWidget> {
  _DynamicWidget();

  int num = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: Colors.redAccent.shade100,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
      
            Text(num.toString()),
      
            IconButton(
              onPressed: (() {
                setState(() {
                  num = num + 1;
                });
              }),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
      
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() { // REMOVING WIDGET
                  WidgetController().removeWidget(widget.controller, widget.index);
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
            ),
      
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And the code that calls this widget is this:
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _Test();
}

class _Test extends State<Test> {

  List<WidgetController> controller = [WidgetController()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              
              ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: controller.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        DynamicWidget(controller: controller, index: index,),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),

              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),

              Center(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() { // ADDING WIDGET
                      WidgetController().addWidget(controller);
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add More'),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The issues I'm running into are:

I can add widgets fine, but cannot visually remove them (widgets are being removed behind the scenes, but not updating in app UI until I refresh by adding another widget)
I'm not sure the indexing is working properly. I think only the end of the widget list is being removed, not the specific widget I am trying to remove

If anyone can alter my code above to fix these issues, it would be very appreciated. I have trying mapping but found that when you add something to one of the created widgets, it is added to all of them.
Please note, this is a simplified version of the source code
